# Can't find Python executable "python2.7.9", you can set the PYTHON env variable

Tags: hyperledger-composer

I'm running below command to setup Hyperledger Composer development tools.
I'm using below command:

```
npm install -g composer-cli
```

But each time I'm getting below error message:

```
gyp ERR! configure error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: **Can't find Python executable "python2.7.9", you can set the PYTHON env variable.**
gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.failNoPython (/Users/vikasbanage/.nvm/versions/node/v8.11.1/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:483:19)
gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.<anonymous> (/Users/vikasbanage/.nvm/versions/node/v8.11.1/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:397:16)
```

I have set up env variable but no luck.
Please help

Comment: is python installed on your system? try which python or python --version Python is installed by the prereqs script for composer.
(I assume you are using a supported OS - Mac or Ubuntu - not Windows)

Comment: @RThatcher : yes python is installed. Version is Python 2.7.9. Also macOS is 10.13.4.